# How do i implement falling pins animation for markers in android map view

Tags: android, android-mapview

Is there any way to implement falling pins/markers animation for google maps in android like that in iPhone ???

Comment: And the answer is: Yes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Android has overlay markers (see ItemizedOverlay) that make it easy to add images to maps, BUT note that, in my experience at least, animated images do not work when added to overlays.

I found it necessary to add a View on top of the MapView, and add imagery to that, and I've successfully added animated drawable images to the map using that approach. For more details see here:
[Can I use AnimationDrawable in an overlay on a MapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407475/can-i-use-animationdrawable-in-an-overlay-on-a-mapview)

But to be honest, you should remember that it's Android, and copying every little feature from iOS is unnecessary. Google Maps on Android doesn't use a pin marker, it uses a static blue spot - I'd say it's best to replicate that and remember your users are Android users, not iOS users - they want consistency across Android apps.

Answer (score -3):

You could have a look in this docmentation: [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#MarkerAnimations)
Here is an example [map](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations).

Just add this in your code:

```
marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
```

Comment: This is for JavaScript, not for android

Comment: JavaScript api v3 works in webview ;) so yes you can, but not in a map view.